# Multi tenant routing in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am running an angular 4 application. I have a specific requirement with respective to routing in my application.

I have routes & route params like `/create/claim`, `/view/claim/:id` etc. These conventional routing methods work fine.

I need to route to a page (eg: a dashboard page) where the `param` is given before the page name. For example

```
http://.../dashboard <--- this is working & loads dashboard module.
http://.../:client-name/dashboard <-- I need to know how to load dashboard module, after getting client-name information from database.
```

Please let me know if anyone had come across such requirement. I would me provided if additional information needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you look is lazy loading and using guards.

- lazy loading: will make your dashboard independent and only accesible when you go to a specific route. More info:

  https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#lazy-loading-modules-with-the-router
- Guards: here will be your request for data because guards will intercept each time you go to a route. Before going to a route you can do the call and verify.

one example

```
 const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',

 }, {
    path: 'dashboard',
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule'
 }, {
   path: 'auth',
   loadChildren: 'app/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
 }
];
```

our guard is like this

```
 canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
  Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authservice.isAuthenticated()){
  return true;
 } else {
  this.router.navigate(['auth/signIn'], {});

  }
 }
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Mauricio,Thanks for quick reply. I am looking for implementing multi tenant routing mechanism where the URL should look like http://www.myapp.com/tenant-1/dashboard, http://www.myapp.com/tenant-2/dashboard. I am already using lazyloading and auth guard services in my app. Kindly let me know how to achieve multi tenancy routing in angular 4 app. Thanks